# How to make a path configurable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am using the following syntax

```
XDocument config = XDocument.Load(@"path to the xml file");
```

But i am inlcuding this statement in the c# code.I want to make the path configurable like 
declare a key in the web.config file of the application with the name path and i should be able to get that in the c# code 
by xdocument cofnig =xdocument.Load(path).

Is it possible this way ?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain where you are having problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it would be sufficient to do the usual:

```
const string key="xmlPath";
...    
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
XDocument config = XDocument.Load(path);
```

This assumes an web.config which contains:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="xmlPath" value="c:\path\to\xml\file.xml" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking how to put a key/value pair into the web.config and later retrieve them in the code.  Please take a look at the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx